# C#, WPF. Как в коде создать кнопки, в указанных ячейках грида

Tags: c#, button

Допустим, есть грид. Разделен на две строки. В верхнем тоже есть грид, который разделен 3 на 3(создаю игру пятнашки). Нужно в коде, создать 8 кнопок(рандомность как нибудь потом добавим), в каждой ячейке кроме одной. http://prntscr.com/jb9xh5 скрин разметки.
и сам код разметки внизу. 
В общем нужно в c# создать кнопки в нужных ячейках

```
 <Window x:Class="Game_PYATNASHKI.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Game_PYATNASHKI"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="Pole">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Как по мне, задавать кнопки через код - дело не очень хорошее, тут нужно использовать инструменты привязок и MVVM.

Самый (как по мне) простой вариант, это использовать ItemsControl, к которой привязывается коллекция со своей VM, которая в свою очередь содержит данные о кнопке.

То есть наша разметка превратиться в нечто подобное:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                </Grid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Row}"/>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Column}"/>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="{Binding Content}" Command="{Binding Command}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

VM кнопки будет на подобие этого:

```
public class ButtonViewModel
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int Row { get; set; }
    public int Column { get; set; }

    public ICommand Command { get; set; }

    public ButtonViewModel(string content, int row = 0, int column = 0, ICommand command = null)
    {
        Content = content;
        Row = row;
        Column = column;
        Command = command;
    }
}
```

Ну и остается создать коллекцию, в которую добавим пару кнопок:

```
public ObservableCollection<ButtonViewModel> Buttons { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ButtonViewModel>();
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;

    Buttons.Add(new ButtonViewModel("aaa"));
    Buttons.Add(new ButtonViewModel("bbb", 1, 1));
    Buttons.Add(new ButtonViewModel("ccc", 2));

}
```

Результатом будет вот такое чудо:

[image: result]

Comment: Возможно, чуть проще было бы с UniformGrid, но там всё равно нужно задавать количество столбцов (или строк).

Comment: @VladD Да, я так хотел написать, но потом подумал, а если к примеру не равномерная таблица автору нужна была бы...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ пример ваш хорош, спору нет.