# Как изменить margin кнопки в коде?

Tags: c#, wpf

В моем окне создается определенное кол-во кнопок в зависимости от выбора пользователя. Поэтому нельзя задавать их дизайн в коде xaml. Как в первую очередь изменить расстояние между кнопками из .cs (кода; в xaml все понятно - Margin="5")?

Comment: Margin = new Thickness(5); Но на самом деле вашу задачу скорее всего надо решать не кодом, а через разметку: привязки, шаблоны, стили – вот это всё

Comment: В [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/820783/c-wpf-Как-в-коде-создать-кнопки-в-указанных-ячейках-грида/820820#820820) я писал о том, как создать динамически кнопки, привязать к ним команду и засунуть в нужные ячейки grid. Советую посмотреть как правильно создавать подобные вещи в WPF. Создавать из кода не очень хорошая идея, стиль объектов это View и он должен быть в View слое, не как иначе..