# Отрисовка объектов на элементе компоновки(Grid, Canvas) взятых из Listbox c использованием MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Я работаю на проектом визуализации карты завода, и мне требуется что бы элементы которые я добавил в ListBox отрисовывались на поле типа Canvas или Grid в указанном месте. ListBox построен по шаблону MVVM. В качестве элементов которые будут отрисовываться используются Polygons. И я не представляю как сделать так что бы элементы уже добавлены появились на поле.

Comment: Если просто разместить в указанном `Grid`, то примерно [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/820820/220553).

Comment: Складывайте элементы в ObservableCollection и привязывайтесь к ней, они будут отображаться автоматически