# Динамическое добавление кнопок в сетку Grid StackPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

Подскажите как добавить в сетку Grid элемента StackPanel кнопки. Мой код:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Width="350" Height="50" Name="ButtonsPanel" Background="#99000000" Orientation="Horizontal" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <Grid>
             <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <RowDefinition Height="50" />
             </Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="350" />
             </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <!-- Put buttons here. -->
        </Grid>
   </StackPanel>
```

Если я статически прописываю кнопки в StackPanel, то всё работает нормально. Кнопки воспринимают **HorizontalAlignment** и **Margin**. Но количество кнопок определяется в зависимости от условий и статический вариант больше не подходит. А если добавляю их программно, то кнопки не отображаются. Если я убираю Grid сетку из StackPanel, то кнопки все собираются в кучу по левому краю.

Добавляю так:

```
var button = new Button
{
    Name = "testButton",
    Content = "Test 1",
    Width = 80,
    Margin = new Thickness(0, 10, 0, 0),
    Style = (Style) Application.Current.FindResource("Flat"),
    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
};

this.ButtonsPanel.Children.Add(button);
```

Естественно кнопок разное количество и параметры **HorizontalAlignment** и **Margin** меняются в зависимости от количества кнопок.

Comment: Почему вы добавляете кнопки вручную, а не с помощью ItemsControl?

Comment: @АндрейNOP потому что я не настолько хорошо знаю возможности языка разметки XAML и пока делаю всё по аналогии базовых уроков.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [C#, WPF. Как в коде создать кнопки, в указанных ячейках грида](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/820783/c-wpf-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%8f%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо. Буду иметь в виду.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оказалось очень просто. Просто нужно было указать x.Name для Grid и обращаться в него, а не в StackPanel. Описание проблемы нашёл только на английском языке на [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/64efe81e-2b89-46fb-ad0f-d8d0f450ebcf/how-to-add-buttons-to-specific-cells-of-grid-in-wpf?forum=wpf).

Теперь код выглядит так:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Width="350" Height="50" Name="ButtonsPanel" Background="#99000000" Orientation="Horizontal" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <Grid x.Name="BlaBlaBLa">
             <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <RowDefinition Height="50" />
             </Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="350" />
             </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <!-- Put buttons here. -->
        </Grid>
   </StackPanel>
```

А код добавления:

```
var button = new Button
{
    Name = "testButton",
    Content = "Test 1",
    Width = 80,
    Margin = new Thickness(0, 10, 0, 0),
    Style = (Style) Application.Current.FindResource("Flat"),
    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
};

this.BlaBlaBLa.Children.Add(button);
```

Возможно кому-то пригодится.