# Как в wpf получить доступ к объектам созданным в коде xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, xaml

Использую в WPF ListView. Что бы при каждом добавлении нового элемента в ListView, в одну из его колонок добавлялась кнопка, я написал следующий код (в коде оставил только одну колонку с кнопкой чтобы не засорять код).

```
<ListView Name="ListViewDictionary" Margin="10,39,92,10">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Озвучить">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Tag ="{Binding vocalizeButton}" Width="20" Height="20" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Кнопки успешно создаются. Но как получить ссылку на них в C# коде или вообще как-то с ними взаимодействовать?

UPD: Просто уточню что меня интересует обработка нажатий этих кнопок.

Comment: У вас не должно быть ссылок на них в коде. У вас должна быть коллекция классов, внутри класса должны быть все эти свойства (`vocalizeButton` например) и уже эта коллекция привязывается к `ListView`. Посмотрите как в WPF работаю привязки.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ну вот vocalizeButton тут как раз свойство типа Button. Как мне привязать создающийся тут Button к vocalizeButton?

Comment: `Button` - это контрол, его место только в XAML, не более.В классе у вас должны быть обычные типы (`int`/`string` и др.). Что касается привязок - посмотрите например [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/820783/220553) ответ, либо куча других примеров, где работают с привязками.

Comment: @mrFieldy вам как и многим другим кто перешел на WPF придется отучиться от нахождения объектов в XAML. тут философия совсем другая. все делается через привязки, шаблоны и т.д. почитайте на www.professorweb.ru

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да это я понимаю. Я к тому, что если мне нужно обработать события нажатия созданной в xaml кнопке, то механизм привязки тут бесполезен. С привязками я примерно знаком.

Comment: @axmed2004 а как мне по другому добавить кнопку  или другой контрол в ListView? (Большое спасибо за ссылку)

Comment: `механизм привязки тут бесполезен` - это почему же? Я вам дал ссылку на ответ, где название, клик и позиция в Grid у кнопки привязаны к классу, к простому классу. Так почему же бесполезны? В WPF не используются обычные события `Click`, да, можно, но это костыли, правильным подходом будет использование привязки к команде (`ICommand`/`RelayCommand` и др.).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ок, сейчас перечитаю, спасибо большое.

Comment: @axmed2004 Это миф, не нужно никуда переучиваться. Использование шаблонов и привязок никак не исключает программное взаимодействие с элементами управления.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не вижу, как для обработки нажатий кнопок нужно получать к ним доступ из кода. Механизм шаблонов точно так же умеет устанавливать и обработчики событий для того, что он генерирует:

```xml
<DataTemplate>
     <Button Width="20" Height="20" Click="Button_Click" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Но, если нужно получить доступ в коде к элементу, сгенерированному шаблоном, конечно, это можно сделать. Проще всего проходить по визуальному дереву; правда следует делать это аккуратно и не завязывать код на определенную его структуру, которая может зависеть от темы оформления. Например, вот так можно найти Button с определенным значением свойства Tag в визуальном дереве:

```
public static Button FindButton(Visual vis, string tag)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(vis); i++)
    {                
        Visual child = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(vis, i);

        Button button = child as Button;
        if (button != null)
        {
            if (tag == (string)button.Tag) return button; 
        }

        Button res = FindButton(child,tag);
        if (res != null) return res;
    }
    return null;
}

Button button = FindButton(ListViewDictionary, "...");
```

Comment: Помогло, спасибо большое.