# Как проверить, какая из кнопок RadioButton выбрана, используя свойство GroupName?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, radiobutton

В коде XAML в Grid создано 3 RadioButton.

```
<RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton_Econom" GroupName="TypeOfCar" Content="Econom ✪" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0" Grid.Row="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Times New Roman" Foreground="#FFFFA700"/>    
        <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton_Standart" GroupName="TypeOfCar" Content="Standart ✪✪" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Times New Roman" Foreground="#FFFFA700"/>    
        <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton_Comfort" GroupName="TypeOfCar" Content="Comfort ✪✪✪" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Times New Roman" Foreground="#FFFFA700"/>
```

Как в коде c# при обработке событий получить доступ к radiobuttons, у которых GroupName - TypeOfCars (без использования GroupBox и так далее)? Нужно для того, чтобы проверить, какой элемент выбран.

Comment: Ну, наверно, использовать привязки? Ну а так, берите `sender` и приводите его к нужному типу, от куда можете взять то, что вам нужно.

Comment: я правильно поняла, что GroupName предназначено, чтобы можно было выбирать только одну из кнопок в пределах имени группы, не более?

Comment: Да. Если `GroupName` один, то при клике на другой элемент этой группы, выделение с первого уберется.

Answer (score 2):

Вы в своем ответе делаете уйму лишних действий.

Смотрите, два решения вам:

## 1. Не используем привязки, используем события

- Чистим ваш XAML от лишнего, все повторы выносим в стиль:

  ```
  <Window.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
          <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
          <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24"/>
          <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
          <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Times New Roman"/>
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFA700"/>
      </Style>
  </Window.Resources>

  <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition/>
          <ColumnDefinition/>
          <ColumnDefinition/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <RadioButton GroupName="TypeOfCar" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Econom ✪" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
      <RadioButton GroupName="TypeOfCar" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="Standart ✪✪" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
      <RadioButton GroupName="TypeOfCar" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Content="Comfort ✪✪✪" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
  </Grid>
  ```
- Подписываем все кнопки на один обработчик события, дописав что то, на подобие:

  ```
  Checked="RadioButton_Checked"
  ```
- Ну и осталось реализовать сам обработчик события:

  ```
  public string SelectedValue { get; private set; }

  private void RadioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      if (sender is RadioButton item)
      {
          SelectedValue = item.Content.ToString();
      }
  }
  ```

Вот и все, в `SelectedValue` вы будете иметь после переключения кнопок нужный вам `Content`.

## 2. Используем привязки

В первом примере ваша проблема заключается в том, что источником данных является контрол, то есть `RadioButton`. Это не есть хорошо! По этой причине лучше данные хранить в отдельном классе. Давайте же сделаем это.

- Создаем класс, который будет содержать в себе группу и контент:

  ```
  public class SomeDataClass
  {
      public SomeDataClass(string group, string content)
      {
          Group = group;
          Content = content;
      }

      public string Group { get; }
      public string Content { get; }
  }
  ```
- Дальше нам нужен класс, который будет служить источником данных. Я лично буду использовать уже существующий `MainWindow`, ибо для одного свойства заводить класс мне нет смысла. Вам же советую сделать отдельный класс!
- Зададим `DataContext`. Тут я советую вам почитать этот [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586), там рассказано как и почему стоит задавать `DataContext`. Я же установлю его просто в том же `MainWindow`, а точнее, в его конструкторе. `this` - это класс источник, в котором должны находится все публичные свойства для привязки:

  ```
  public MainWindow()
  {
      InitializeComponent();
      DataContext = this;
  }
  ```
- Теперь нам надо сделать коллекцию и заполнить ее нужными данными. Так, как я указал `DataContext = this`, то и коллекцию я буду делать в `MainWindow` классе:

  ```
  public List<SomeDataClass> Data { get; } = new List<SomeDataClass>
  {
      new SomeDataClass("TypeOfCar", "Econom ✪"),
      new SomeDataClass("TypeOfCar", "Standart ✪✪"),
      new SomeDataClass("TypeOfCar", "Comfort ✪✪✪")
  };
  ```
- Все, осталось привязать это. Так, как используется коллекция, то и в XAML надо выбрать соответствующий элемент:

  ```
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <RadioButton GroupName="{Binding Group}" Content="{Binding Content}" />
          </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </ItemsControl>
  ```

Вот и все, в результате вы получите нужные `RadioButton`, которые не зависимы от XAML, имеют свой источник данных. Остается только получить то, что сейчас выбрано и тут конечно посложнее в этом плане будет. Самый простой способ как по мне - использовать команды:

- Реализуем интерфейс `ICommand`. Я возьму код из [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/616413):

  ```
  public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
  {
      public RelayCommand(Action<T> onExecute) { OnExecute = onExecute; }

      public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
      public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => true;
      public void Execute(object parameter) => OnExecute((T)parameter);

      readonly Action<T> OnExecute;
  }
  ```
- Создадим свойство выбранного объекта, свойство команды и метод, который нам сделает что то при клике:

  ```
  public SomeDataClass SelectedItem { get; set; }

  public ICommand SelectionChengedCommand { get; private set; }

  public MainWindow()
  {
      InitializeComponent();
      DataContext = this;
      SelectionChengedCommand = new RelayCommand<SomeDataClass>(SelectionChenged);
  }

  private void SelectionChenged(SomeDataClass item) => SelectedItem = item;
  ```
- Осталось привязать в XAML элементы к команде:

  ```
  <RadioButton GroupName="{Binding Group}" 
                  Content="{Binding Content}" 
                  Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectionChengedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"
                  CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
  ```

Тут поясню:

- `Command` - привязка к команде, которая находится в `DataContext`.
- `RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}` - так, как у нас коллекция, то по умолчанию свойство для привязки будет искаться внутри объекта, который сейчас коллекции. Что бы перейти на уровень выше нам надо задать `RelativeSource`, который найдет объект с типом `ItemsControl` (контрол, который используем для отображения коллекции).
- `DataContext.SelectionChengedCommand` - В найденном `RelativeSource`объекте мы берем свойство `SelectionChengedCommand` из `DataContext` элемента.
- `CommandParameter="{Binding}"` - параметром команды задаем весь класс.

Все, теперь у нас при выборе нового объекта всегда будет отрабатываться команда, которая обновит нам текущий выбранный элемент. Тут по сути вариантов много, как можно подобное реализовать, хоть в `ListBox` засовывайте и стилями с триггерами задавайте значения. Я лишь показал сам принцип, а дальше уже сами.

P.S. Вы могли заметить, что вариант с привязками не в нужных нам ячейках. Исправить это можно при помощи например [такого решения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/820820/220553).

Comment: Спасибо огромное, что заморочились и так детально расписали! Теперь стало понятно, о чем вы говорите, и как это сделать 

Answer (score 0):

В общем, сделала так:

Метод:

```cs
    private void WalkLogicalTree(List<RadioButton> radioButtons, object parent)    
    {
      DependencyObject doParent = parent as DependencyObject;
      if (doParent == null) return;
      foreach (object child in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(doParent))
       {
        if (child is RadioButton && (child as RadioButton).GroupName == "TypeOfCar")
         {
          radioButtons.Add(child as RadioButton);
         }
        }
    }
```

В обработчике нужного события затаскиваю в лист радиобаттоны с нужным GroupName:

```cs
    List<RadioButton> radioButtons = new List<RadioButton>();
    WalkLogicalTree(radioButtons, Grid_Taxi);
```

и с ним уже дальше работаю (вывод информации).

```cs
String FindCheckedRadioButtonName()
        {
            List<RadioButton> radioButtons = new List<RadioButton>();
            WalkLogicalTree(radioButtons, Grid_Taxi);
            foreach (var item in radioButtons)
            {
                if (item.IsChecked == true)
                {
                    return item.Content.ToString();
                }
            }
            return "None";
        }
```

Comment: Как это относится к вопросу? Он про "Как проверить, какая кнопка выбрана",а вы просто собираете все кнопки с `GroupName == "TypeOfCar" `. Да и рекурсия зачем? Да и поиск дочернего элемента, `DependencyObject`...? Как все это относится к тому, что вы задали? Хорошо, если не хотите использовать привязки (что очень зря), то  просто подпишите как я вам и говорил ранее все кнопки на 1 событие и из `sender`'a берите нужную информацию. `<RadioButton x:Name="Radio1" GroupName="1" Checked="RadioButton_Checked" />` и в обработчике `if (sender is RadioButton item) Debug.WriteLine($"Имя: {item.Name}");`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ отредктировала ответ, рекурсию убрала, она действительно лишняя. Плюс добавила, каким образом использую потом лист радиобаттонов.

П.С. Уровень знакомства с c# - несколько месяцев, с xaml, wpf - две недели.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я не сделала через привязки, потому что не до конца поняла, что именно вы имели в виду, плюс зациклилась на желании таки применить свойство Group.Name.