# Как в WPF привязаться к команде во ViewModel из Model DataContext?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Используя шаблон `MVVM` создаю несколько экземпляров модели данных и упаковываю их в `List` для хранения в `ViewModel`. Затем по клику на `UserControl` привязанном к модели, с помощью `RelayCommand`, в коллекции будет меняться состояние свойства модели (для простоты цвет фона), а задача `UserControl` отобразить изменения во `View`.

**BorderControl.xaml**

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="TestWpfApp.BorderControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWpfApp"
             mc:Ignorable="d">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding Path=Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding Path=Height, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:BorderControl}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>            
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=Background, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Border/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```

**BorderModel.cs**

```cs
class BorderModel
    {
        public SolidColorBrush Background { get; set; } = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Wheat);
    }
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```cs
class ViewModel
    {
        private RelayCommand controlClickedCommand;

        public List<BorderModel> Models { get; set; } = new List<BorderModel>()
        {
            {new BorderModel() }, {new BorderModel()}, {new BorderModel()}
        };

        public RelayCommand ControlClickedCommand => controlClickedCommand ?? new RelayCommand(ControlClicked);

        private void ControlClicked(object args)
        {
            Models[0].Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }
    }
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window x:Class="TestWpfApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWpfApp"        
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Models}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:BorderControl/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Тестовый запуск:
[image: Тестовый запуск]

Для того, чтобы привязаться и выполнить команду `ControlClickedCommand` в `ViewModel` я могу использовать `InputBindings` в `BorderControl`:

```xml
<ControlTemplate>
    <Border>
      <Border.InputBindings>
          <MouseBinding Command="{Binding ControlClickedCommand}" MouseAction="LeftClick"/>
      </Border.InputBindings>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Но из-за то, что `DataContext` у `Border` это `BorderModel` упакованная в `List`, не понятно, как привязаться к `RelayCommand ControlClickedCommand ViewModel` при клике по `BorderControl`.

Comment: Можно конечно решить, но почему бы команду не перенести в `BorderModel`? Тогда вопрос решится сам собой.

Comment: Пока не понимаю как запускать команду из `BorderModel`, можно подробнее?

Comment: Берете весь код, связанный с командой, переносите в класс `BorderModel`, больше ничего не нужно. Ну и вместо `Models[0].Background` - просто `Background`

Comment: у вас кстати ошибка `=> controlClickedCommand ??`, должно быть `=> controlClickedCommand ??=`

Comment: А вам не кажется, что у вас тут нарушение MVVM? Вот давайте по порядку: `SolidColorBrush Background` - цвет, это к чему относится? Это данные, UI или что-то еще? Скорей всего это UI, то есть View слой, верно? Тогда что у вас цвет делает в Model (слой данных)? Ок, предположим это чисто ради примера, но команда, это какой слой? Вот есть 3 слоя: Model - источник данных (база, файл на диске, сервер и др.), View - интерфейс и взаимодействие с пользователем (то, что он видит), и ViewModel - слой, который обрабатывает действия пользователя и делает что-то с Model слоем. Так где должны быть команды?

Comment: Идея в том, чтобы при клике по элементу (слой View) перебирать массив объектов (слой Model) и менять свойства у нужного (слой ViewModel). `SolidColorBrush Background` приведён для упрощения примера. А команды - это способ взаимодействия между слоями.

Comment: `А команды - это способ взаимодействия между слоями.` вооот, так почему вы ее хотите перенести или как-либо с ней взаимодействовать из Model слоя? Он знать даже не должен что-либо о V и VM слое, а вы его вдруг ответственным за команду сделать хотите. Также мне не понравилось `DataContext у Border это BorderModel` - то есть вы изначально проигнорировали существование VM слоя и привязались к Model, может из-за этого тогда у вас все трудности?

Comment: Смотрите как обычно это делается: ` при клике по элементу` - в VM слое команда и ее обработчик, который по клику вызывает метод из модели. Сама команда естественно привязана в V слое. Также рядом с командой находится список VM объектов, которые являются оберткой над M объектами, они в себе содержат лишь то, что необходимо для View слоя, для привязок. Далее, `перебирать массив объектов` - это обычно делают методом в M слое, который возвращает после завершения нужный список обратно. `и менять свойства у нужного` - подписываетесь на событие обновления коллекции и все изменения переносите в M слой

Comment: К сожалению, так и не получил ответа на свой вопрос. Зато критики, хотя и не просил, получил достаточно. Например: `Также мне не понравилось DataContext у Border это BorderModel` - странно, что у View контекст данных это Model в MVVM, да? Вопрос был в том, как из контекста данных UserControl получить доступ к контексту данных VM.

Comment: Очень помогла вот [эта ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1050002/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA-radiobutton-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-groupname), всё подробно расписано, @EvgeniyZ, спасибо!