# Как ускорить DataGrid или я могу реализовать свою сетку изображений в ListViews

Tags: wpf, datagrid

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Приветствую!
Я создал простую программу, для вставки выбранных картинок в ячейки , для реализации сетки с ячейками я выбрал DataGrid, было достаточно трудно, это мое первое приложение.  но в конце меня ожидал сюрприз, DataGrid оказался сложным в масштабировании, когда ячеек  100х100, сетка рисуется 5 секунд, это не так важно, важно то что когда я нажимаю на ячейке происходит изменение значения

```
<Image Source="{Binding}"/>
```

для того что б я немедленно увидел изменение мне приходиться делать

```
MyDataGrid.Items.Refresh();
```

Что вызывает задержку в 5 секунд если ячеек 100х100 .
Вопрос:
Как мне ускорить обновление DataGrid или можно обойти DataGrid.Items.Refresh ?

Я пробовал реализовать сетку на ListView но у меня не получилось создать динамическую сетку.

Мне неважно каким классом рисовать сетку.

Comment: Ну для начала не используйте контролы, как источник данных, научитесь использовать привязки, заведите коллекцию `string`, которая будет содержать пути до картинок и вы уже в разы ускорите ваше приложение.

Comment: контролы, это DataGrid ? Я привязываю <imege> он в Cell Datatemple и привязан к значению ячейки DataTable .

Comment: Создайте класс, который будет содержать в себе информацию ячейки (картинку, может название, методы взаимодействия и так далее), то есть некий класс, который не содержит в себе нечего лишнего, только данные ячейки. Дальше сделайте класс, который вы установите как источник данных, в нем сделайте публичное свойство `public ObservableCollection<ВашКлассЯчейки> Cells {get;}`, после задайте класс "данных", как `DataContext` у окна (`DataContext = new ВашКлассГдеЛежитСвойствоCells();`). Все, вот у вас уже часть готовой привязки, где нет нечего лишнего, остается сделать дизайн.

Comment: Спасибо, звучит красиво и просто, буду пробовать. Я не смог установить DataContext = new MyClassDataSource(); в mainwindow.cs я сделал так, можно так делать?      <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

Comment: У вас нет MVVM и чего либо подобного, но лучше в это направление идти, а по его правилам такое [нельзя делать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553). У меня кстати есть один [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/820820/220553), где я размещал элементы в сетке по правилам MVVM, думаю вам будет полезно, ну а так, Grid вы можете заменить на все, что вашей душе угодно, главное понять сам принцип, а точнее - не использовать контролы как источник данных. Тут еще есть [такой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/632894/220553), там использовали вообще `Canvas`.

Comment: Я смотрел ваш ответ, понравилась концепция. А можно ли изменять количество Grid.ColumnDefinitions и Grid.RowDefinitions во время выполнения , если Grid в ItemsPanelTemplate . Мне нужно будет добавлять и удалять строки.

Comment: Не забывайте оповещать человека через `@ник`, а то случайно зашел сюда и увидел комментарий новый. Вам скорей всего придется писать расширение, нечто на подобие [этого](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-grids-rowcolumn-count-properties/).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо вам огромное, за правильные наставления, я как раз пробую GridHelpers .