# WPF просто Grid Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, wpf-grid

Необходимо динамически добавлять юзер контролы. Подскажите возможно ли реализовать привязку самого грида, а если нет, то подайте идею как это можно реализовать.

```
<Grid x:Name="Screen" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Margin="20"></Grid>
```

```
List<int> mass = new List<int>();
List<Label> numbs = new List<Label>();
private void GenerateNumb(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            Screen.Children.Clear();
            mass = new List<int>();
            if (numberstring.Text.Length==0)
            {
                return;
            }
            int c = Convert.ToInt32(numberstring.Text);
           
            for (int i=0;i<c; i++)
            {
                mass.Add(rnd.Next());
                ColumnDefinition c1 = new ColumnDefinition();
                Screen.ColumnDefinitions.Add(c1);
                numbs.Add(new Label());
                Screen.Children.Add(numbs[i]);
                Grid.SetColumn(numbs[i], i);
                numbs[i].Content = mass[i];
            }
        }
```

Немного другой код

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Columns="3" Rows="3"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

```cs
class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop ="") 
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }


        public List<ButtonViewModel> _Buttons { get;  set; } = new List<ButtonViewModel>();
        public List<ButtonViewModel> Buttons
        {
            get
            {
                return _Buttons;
            }
            set
            {
                _Buttons = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }



        public class ButtonViewModel
        {
            public string Text
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public ICommand Command { get; set; }

            public ButtonViewModel(string text)
            {
                Text = text;
            }
        }









        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            Buttons.Add(new ButtonViewModel("1"));
            Buttons.Add(new ButtonViewModel("2"));
            Buttons.Add(new ButtonViewModel("3"));
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
                    var Mytmp= Buttons[1];
                    Buttons[1] = Buttons[0];
                    Buttons[0] = Mytmp;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: `<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">...`

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/attached-properties-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так это делается.

Верстку каждого элемента коллекции через `ItemTemplate`, а контрол, который будет служить контейнером - через `ItemsPanelTemplate` задается, можно использовать [любую разновидность панели](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/panels-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). То что вы ищете - это возможно `UniformGrid` ([ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid?view=net-5.0)).

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <local:MyControl Text="{Binding ...}" .../>
            <Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemControl>
```

Comment: Зачем тут `Grid` на каждый item? Ну а так, я прям вот вангую, что человек не знает что должно быть в `MyCollection`. Ну и, в таком виде, это [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/820820/220553).

Comment: Очень плохо, что лень, ибо это нарушение установленных правил и мы обязаны перед тем, как писать ответы проверить, есть ли похожее на SO, а их вы сами знаете, уйма. Я понимаю, что SO, это помойка, но зачем гадить-то еще сильнее?

Comment: Не, против самого ответа (его содержимого) я не имею ничего против, ответ как ответ, в нем нету чего-либо сверхъестественного или наоборот, так что тут не берите на свой счет. Вы знаете, что я за порядок на SO всеми руками, но увы, мы с вами прекрасно знаем, что на него плевать всем другим (включая модераторов) из-за чего тут много вопросов, которые уже были заданы или которым тут попросту не место. По этой причине я и говорю вам, что это дубликат и хотелось бы, чтоб вы вместо ответов на подобное, искали бы дубли и голосовали за закрытие, но увы, вам "лень" и "всё равно" как и всем другим.

Comment: @aepot Я всё ещё плохо понимаю, не подскажешь как правильно стоит преобразовать это под wpf?

Comment: ТСу можно же предложить Attached Property? Разве нет?

Comment: @HamsterVas это и есть WPF. Назначьте `DataContext`, сделайте ваш массив доступным публично через свойство. Это и есть привязка данных. Это всё легко гуглится, если совсем непонятно. Ключевой момент - вам не нужно динамически создавать контролы в коде, `ItemsControl` сделает это за вас, вам нужно только скормить ему данные. А юзерконтрол внутри просто привяжите к нужному свойству или к самому элементу коллекции. Примеров того, о чем я сейчас пишу - полинтернета.

Comment: Что и требовалось в итоге ожидать, привет бессмысленный дубликат, который бесполезен для SO и даже бесполезен и непонятен для автора вопроса. Сам же вопрос вряд ли закроется, ибо тут люди не умеют голосовать за закрытие. Будет в итоге висеть как [куча](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1202186/220553) других.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ как и куча бессмысленных коментариев под этим постом. Я свои почистил кстати.

Comment: Ну это ваше право, а я свои, пожалуй, оставлю.

Comment: @HamsterVas Я хочу, чтоб на этом сайте соблюдались простейшие правила, а первый [их пункт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) о чем гласит? Правильно, "ищите перед тем, как задать вопрос", я дал вон самым первым комментарием ссылку на дубликат, могу еще найти уйму таких. Также, изначально ваш вопрос был непонятным текстом, под которым можно было многое понять, из-за чего его и закрыли. К вам у меня претензий нет, новичок и все дела, но вот к автору этого вопроса, который здесь уже почти год, они есть, ибо "лень". Сейчас вопрос закрыт, он сам удалиться через некое время.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ болезненный перфекционизм. Он меня лишил работы даже один раз. Теперь я выбираю, где надо, а где нет. Мир под себя не переделаешь. Если вам так хочется изменить SO к лучшему, что же вы не пошли в модераторы? Я бы даже за вас голос отдал. Видимо потому что это тяжелая работа, требующая кучи времени и терпения. И даже там пошатнуть манеру создания контента у сообщества вам было бы тяжело. А здесь, сидя в комментах у меня в ответе вы тем более ничего не решите. Переубеждение возможно только тогда, когда есть спорный момент. Здесь его нет. Остальное всё только слова. С уважением.

Comment: @aepot Да как вы не поймете то, я не хочу чего-либо менять, даже больше скажу, я многое допускают тут того, что нельзя по правилам, но я хочу порядка и чтоб люди следовали хоть немного поставленным правилам, не уж то это так трудно? Я пойму новичков, который только зашли сюда и считают это простым форумом, но вот вы, например, к чему был этот ответ, ради + в репутацию или благие намерения? Вы ведь прекрасно знаете, что вопросы удаляет система на которых нету ответов и которые с низкой оценкой, но нет, даем ответ, его лайкают и тем самым вопрос висит вечно в базе SO и все ради чего?

Comment: @aepot А модераторы, я думаю вы тоже прекрасно знаете, что они тут бесполезны, ибо связаны многим и многого не могут, вспомнить, например случай про человека, который каждый день создавал новый акк и задавал с него вопрос, сделали что? Нет, до сих пор тот человек может также это продолжать. А по поводу комментариев, нету смысла писать посты на той же мете или еще где, призывать публику и так далее, вон, до сих пор решают нужны конкурсы на SO или нет, уже какой год, но вот напомнить человеку, который делает что-то неверно, сразу, по горячим следам, иногда очень даже помогает.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ открою вам секрет, меня в целом всё что здесь происходит - полностью устраивает. Я испрользую SO в своих личных эгоистичных целях - набиваю здесь экспу в кодинге, и за год я уже благодаря в том числе вам вырос из адского джуна в возможно неплохого мидла, и дальше буду расти. А репа, контент и ваше мнение об этом - всего-лишь побочные эффекты, которые не делают ни хуже, не лучше. Не измеряйте мир по своим ценностям, мы с вами здесь наверняка по совершенно разным причинам, либо отдавайте при себе отчет, что это ваши субъективные ценности, и они могут быть расхожими например с моими.

Comment: @HamsterVas, если у вас возник новый вопрос - задайте его отдельно.

Comment: @aepot Ну вот что и требовалось доказать, вы, к сожалению, как и многие здесь, готовы ради репутации нарушить даже принятые тут правила и порядки. И тут мы с вами друг друга вряд ли когда поймем, ибо я, ради "заработка" не переступлю через черту закона и порядка, а вы, судя по вашим ответам, наоборот. Повторюсь, я не меняю тут чего либо, а наоборот, следую тому, что тут принято. С чего вы вообще взяли, что я хочу изменить SO? К чему эти "не изменяйте мир по своим ценностям"? Вот вы в магазине крадете кусок хлеба, я вижу это и говорю вам, "ну парень, ну не делай так", это я меняю мир?

Comment: @aepot А по поводу `которые не делают ни хуже, не лучше` - ну, этот вопрос как минимум закрылся, думаете без этого разговора вы бы поставили свой голос? Я уверен, что нет, а другие бы прошли мимо, ибо есть ответ. Повлияло это на что-то, я считаю, что да, как и в многих других случаях. Буду я дальше это делать? Да, иногда "ткнуть носом" человека в его проступок бывает очень эффективно. А на этой ноте, я дальнейшего поводя для разговора не вижу, ибо я вас понял, как думаю и вы меня, чего уж дальше мусолить одно и тоже? Удачи.

Comment: @HamsterVas оформите как новый вопрос.