# Как передать кнопке текст из IEnumerable<string>?

Tags: c#, wpf, active-directory

Полный вопрос такой:
WPF. Мне нужно в Grid (или в каком элементе лучше? Я совсем зеленый) сделать динамически создаваемые кнопки, которые отображают имена найденных пользователей в AD. Как мне динамически создать кнопки и как передать в них каждый элемент из IEnumerable?
Мой код IEnumerable string

```
 public IEnumerable<string> UsersList(string UserName)
        {
            DirectoryEntry rootDSE = new DirectoryEntry(GetCurrentDomainPath());

            DirectorySearcher userSearch = new DirectorySearcher(rootDSE)
            {
                PageSize = 50,
                Filter = "(&(objectCategory=User)(objectClass=person)(name=" + UserName + "*))"
        };
            userSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");

            using (var results = userSearch.FindAll())
            {
                foreach (SearchResult result in results)
                {
                    yield return (string)result.Properties["name"][0];
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/820820/220553

Comment: Мне кажется, что более уместным, чем создание кнопок здесь смотрится создание выпадающего списка.

Answer (score 0):

если я правильно понял, то решение следующее:
Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflowQuestHelp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverflowQuestHelp"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" x:Name="ThisWindow">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel></local:MainWindowViewModel>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Users}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Button Content="{Binding .}"></Button>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid></Window>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
    private IEnumerable<string> _Users;
    public IEnumerable<string> Users
    {
        get { return _Users; }
        set
        {
            _Users = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        ObservableCollection<string> Users = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)//Генерируем пользователей у вас они должны подтягиваться из AD
        {
            Users.Add("User" + i);
        }
        this.Users = Users;
    }
}
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вы хотите, действительно динамического обновления, то коллекция, которая будет биндится к ItemsControl должна реализовывать INotifyCollectionChanged, например ObservableCollection

Comment: Всем спасибо! Я только только начинаю, поэтому не досмотрел и не знал про элемент ListBox. Сделал через него