# Как подгрузить код xaml через c#

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

Необходимо через c# подгрузить следующий код на xaml при загрузке окна на страницу xamarin.
фрагмент кода, который необходимо подгрузить:

```
            <Grid>
            <!-- Создание строки для клеток -->
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                <!-- Добавьте сколько строк нужно -->
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <!-- Создание колонки для клеток -->
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                <!-- Добавьте сколько колонок нужно -->
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <!-- Создание клеток -->
            <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="Black" />
            <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="White" />
            <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" BackgroundColor="Black" />

            <BoxView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="White" />
            <BoxView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="Black" />
            <BoxView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" BackgroundColor="White" />

            <BoxView Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="Black" />
            <BoxView Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="White" />
            <BoxView Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" BackgroundColor="Black" />
            <!-- Создайте сколько нужно BoxView элементов для клеток -->
        </Grid>
```

подгрузить надо в некоторый `<Frame x:name='coloras'><Frame/>`
В xamarin я новобранец, знаю как подобное проворачивается в chtml, подскажите, как здесь поступить

Comment: Почему XAML? Почему не вынести из него нужные данные в простые классы, которые потом просто сереализовать/десереализовать в JSON/XML, или любой другой нужный формат? Вот к примеру размещение объекта [в нужной ячейке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/820820/220553), заметьте, все данные в простом классе, который содержит лишь контент, да и два числа. В вашем случае контентом будет цвет. С сеткой правда придется повозиться, делая что-то вроде [этого](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-grids-rowcolumn-count-properties/). P.S. Это WPF, но в Xamarin примерно все тож самое.

Comment: Хранение данных в UI - плохая идея. Как я понял, это вам ChatGPT насоветовал такое? Не доверяйте боту. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1255542/373567 вот смотрите как я делал шахматную доску с помощью конвертера в WPF, в Xamarin почти так же можно.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ в Xamarin Toolkit есть `UniformGrid`, можно прибиндить количество строк и колонок, и привязаться к обычной коллекции.

Comment: Этот вопрос можно улучшить, почитайте: [Что такое «Ошибка молотка» или «Ошибка XY»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/373567)

Comment: @aepot `UniformGrid` есть и в WPF, только вот он не позволит сделать некоторое задуманное. Если элементы размещаются по типу "шахматной доски", то без проблем (как и сказал в своем ответе по первой ссыкле в комментариях), в других случаях, без нормальной сетки не обойтись.