# Как лучше всего добавить элементы в несколько рядов

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть 6 условных рядов в xaml, в будущем их может быть больше. Как лучше и эффективнее всего добавить элементы в row, между элементами может быть расстояние, они могут стоять впритык, или в ряду вообще может и не быть элементов. Ниже прикрепляю пример того, как нужно сделать[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я бы сделал так: каждая строка - 1) отдельный Grid, т.к. у вас на скрине явно видно, что колонки могут быть разного размера на каждой строке. А складывать это всё можно, например, в StackPanel; 2) Опять берем контейнер StackPanel, но складываем туда уже WrapPanel, который по умолчанию горизонтально разместит ваши элементы;

Comment: спасибо, я как раз так и решил сделать. Тогда другой вопрос, вот у меня внутри есть элементы(желтые прямоугольники), в будущем их будет очень много, а это проблемы частотой кадров и прогрузкой элементов, почитав про виртуализацию, мне кажется, что мне нужен какой-то контейнер, параметры которого я буду просто редактировать и будет создаваться просто измененная версия одного контейнера. Как лучше это сделать?

Comment: Может лучше подумать над пагинацией в таком случае? Держать over9000 элементов тоже как-то не очень будет. Если пагинация ну совсем никак, то тут не подскажу, опыта такого не было. Да и вообще, на сколько я помню, то WPF не будет перерисовывать весь ваш контейнер, а только то, что было изменено (могу ошибаться).

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/820820/220553 - по аналогии составляйте себе сетку какого угодно размера, и сколько угодно ячеек, будет то, что хотите.